# Complex Query, LISTAGG, PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle11gr2, listagg

I have got the following two scenarios and desired output.  Not sure if LISTAGG or PIVOT can be used.

Need help on the best way to write the SQL query to achieve the desired output.

Here is what I tried so far.  However, I've not considered AUTH.  I'm looking query considering AUTH and should be extensible if more columns are added.

```
    SELECT CLM_TYPE_CSV,
     LISTAGG (PROGRAM, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PROGRAM)
        AS PROGRAM_CSV
    FROM (  SELECT PROGRAM,
           LISTAGG (CLAIM_TYPE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CLAIM_TYPE)
              AS CLM_TYPE_CSV
          FROM STG_EDIT_DISP_PARAM
         WHERE ERR_NUM = '001'
      GROUP BY PROGRAM)
    GROUP BY CLM_TYPE_CSV
```

Appreciate help!
 --####SCENARIO 1############

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    ERR_NUM |   PROGRAM |   CLAIM_TYPE  |   AUTH    |   
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    001     |    BLG    |   P           |     Y 
    001     |    ENG    |   O           |     Y 
    001     |    ENG    |   P           |     Y 
    001     |    FED    |   O           |     Y 
    001     |    FED    |   P           |     Y 
    001     |    FED    |   Q           |     Y
```

Desired output:

```
     --------------------------------------------------------
     ERR_NUM    |   PROGRAM    | CLAIM_TYPE   |    AUTH |
     --------------------------------------------------------
     001        |    BLG       |    P         |      Y
     001        |    ENG,FED   |    O,P       |      Y
     001        |    FED       |    Q         |      Y
```

--####SCENARIO 2############-----------------------------

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    ERR_NUM       |    PROGRAM  |  CLAIM_TYPE  |    AUTH    |
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    001           |    BLG      |   P          |    N
    001           |    ENG      |   O          |    Y
    001           |    ENG      |   P          |    N
    001           |    FED      |   O          |    Y
    001           |    FED      |   P          |    Y
    001           |    FED      |   Q          |    Y   
    001           |    FED      |   X          |    N
```

Desired output:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ERR_NUM     |  PROGRAM         | CLAIM_TYPE   | AUTH    |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    001         |    BLG,ENG       |    P         | N
    001         |    ENG,FED       |    O         | Y
    001         |    FED           |    P,Q       | Y
    001         |    FED           |    X         | N
```

Comment: What queries have you tried so far? Would you please edit your question and add them?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guide for the First scenario ( and I wish you studied for the second one ).

First of all, you need *LISTAGG* but not *PIVOT*.

As you focus on the columns `program` and `claim_type`, consider the repeating and non-repeating values seperately as in the following solution ( by using `having(count(...))` structures ) :

```
select err_num,
       listagg(program,',') within group (order by program) as program, 
       max(claim_type) as claim_type,
       auth
  from
(
  select err_num,program,
         min(claim_type)||','||max(claim_type) as claim_type,
         auth
    from tab
   where claim_type in 
  (
  select claim_type
    from tab
   group by claim_type 
   having count(claim_type)>1
  )
   group by program, err_num, auth 
   having count(program)>1
)  
group by claim_type, err_num, auth
union all
select err_num, program, claim_type, auth
  from tab
 where program in 
  (
    select program
      from tab
     group by program 
     having count(program)=1
  )
union all  
select err_num, program, claim_type, auth
  from tab
 where claim_type in 
  (
    select claim_type
      from tab
     group by claim_type 
     having count(claim_type)=1
  ) 
order by program, claim_type;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76e327/85)

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to:

- Group the rows by err_num, auth
- For each claim_type within these grouping, find how many programs there are
- Return a comma separated list of the distinct programs and claim types which are in the same group calculated in step 2?

If so, you can use analytics to calculate the program count for each err_num, auth, & claim_type. Include this count in your final group by.

To get listagg to return distinct values, map the program and claim_type to null if they're not the first in the current group. You can do this by passing the values to row_number, returning the column when this is one. And null otherwise.

Which gives:

```
create table tab (
  err_num varchar2(3), program varchar2(3), 
  claim_type varchar2(3), auth varchar2(3)
);

insert all 
   into tab values ('001','BLG','P','N') 
   into tab values ('001','ENG','O','Y')
   into tab values ('001','ENG','P','N')
   into tab values ('001','FED','O','Y') 
   into tab values ('001','FED','P','Y')
   into tab values ('001','FED','Q','Y')
   into tab values ('001','FED','X','N')
select * from dual;   

with rws as (
  select t.*, row_number () over ( order by err_num, program, claim_type ) rn,
         count (*) over ( partition by err_num, claim_type, auth ) grp_count
  from   tab t
), grps as (
  select r.*,
         case
           when row_number () over ( partition by claim_type, auth, grp_count order by 1 ) = 1 then
             claim_type
         end claim_first,
         case
           when row_number () over ( partition by program, auth, grp_count order by 1 ) = 1 then
             program
         end prog_first
  from   rws r 
)
  select err_num, 
         listagg ( prog_first, ',' ) within group ( order by rn ) progs,
         listagg ( claim_first, ',' ) within group ( order by rn ) claims,
         auth
  from   grps
  group  by err_num, auth, grp_count;

ERR_NUM   PROGS     CLAIMS   AUTH   
001       FED       X        N      
001       BLG,ENG   P        N      
001       FED       P,Q      Y      
001       ENG,FED   O        Y
```

HT to Laurent Schneider for his many distinct listaggs method https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2014/05/distinct-listagg.html